# OpenGL - Alpha Blending Lights

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, lighting

I am having trouble getting my lights to blend together properly. Basically, what I am doing is getting all the obstacles, and drawing a quad for the shadow (just extending the positions of the obstacle).

Here is a screenshot of that I am trying to say: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObD4i.png

As you can see, both lights are casting shadows, but the the alpha is not blending right.

I really don't know what else to say, if you need anything, just ask. Thank you all for reading.

EDIT: I thought that I would add that I am not using frame buffers, I am just looping through every light and rendering it.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "the alpha is not blending right." What doesn't look right to you? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: If you look at the screenshot I provide, you will see that the shadows are not blending. The last light to be rendered is compleatly opaque, while the others alpha lowers as you go back in the loop.

Comment: I can barely see anything in the image. I see 2 lights, one purple, one yellow. If I look really hard, I can just barely make out some squares that look like maybe they're casting shadows, but it's really hard to tell. Can you make a brighter image that shows the problem?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought the picture was clearer! I'll try and get a new one when I get back from school tomorrow.